# Android Null Exception on Calling function

Tags: android, canvas

I want to change color on button click by passing color integer as a parameter but on click the android throws an error of Null Pointer Exception. and application crashes .. i am stuck here kindly help me please 
function name is SetColor()

```
   MyView Class

  public class MyView extends Activity {

   Button brushLarge;
   Button brushMeduim;
   Button brushSmall;
   Button erase;
   Button save;
   Button trash;
   Button rainbow;
   Button color1;
    Button color2;
        Button color3;
     this.color1 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.color1));
     this.color2 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.color2));
     this.color3 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.color3));
      this.color1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View paramView)
        {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "color1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //MyView.this.coloringView.setColor("#CD5C5C");
        }
      });
      this.color2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View paramView)
        {
            //DrawView.changePaintColor(0xFFFF0000);0);
            try
            {coloringView.changePaintColor(0xFFFF0000); 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "color1"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            //coloringView.changePaintColor(0xFFFF0000);    
        }
      });
      this.color3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View paramView)
        {
          MyView.this.coloringView.setColor("#FA8072");
        }
      });
      return;
    }
}

  DrawView Class    

    public class DrawView extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
    private Path circlePath = new Path();
    Canvas mCanvas;
    String color = "#ffee22";


      public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(15f);

        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
mCanvas=new Canvas();
    }
       public void changePaintColor(int color){
            this.paint.setColor(color);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // Gives you x and y coordinates on the Event.
        float pointX = event.getX();
        float pointY = event.getY();

        // Checks for the event that occurs
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);

            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
            circlePath.reset();

            // (circle's center x-coordinate, y-coordinate, radius of the
            // circle, direction to wind the shape)
            circlePath.addCircle(pointX, pointY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
            //circlePath.addRect(pointX - 25, pointY - 25, pointX + 25, pointY + 25, Path.Direction.CW);
/*          RectF rect = new RectF(pointX - 25, pointY - 25, pointX + 25, pointY + 25);
            circlePath.addRoundRect(rect, 0, 0, Path.Direction.CW);
*/
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            circlePath.reset();

            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }

        // Schedules a repaint.
        // Force a view to draw.
        postInvalidate();
        return true;
    }
/////function------------------------------------
    public void apple()
    {
    //  paint.setColor(ap);
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Rehman", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.paint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);


    }


    public void setColor(String color)
    {


        this.paint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);    
    }
    public void onSizeChange(int paramInt)
      {
       paint.setStrokeWidth(paramInt);
      }
      public void clear()
      {
        if (this.mCanvas != null)
        {
          this.paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
          mCanvas.drawPaint(this.paint);
          invalidate();
          paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(this.color));
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: Looks like `coloringView` is not initialized.

Comment: where is your `onCreate`?

Comment: have you tried the below post. i guess what you want is a fingerpaint and an option for the user to choose the color of his choice. instead of buttons use a color picker. i have posted the code below. try it and let me know if it works. Also you have asked 4 questions accepted none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `onCreate`

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.color1 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.color1));
    this.color2 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.color2));
    this.color3 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.color3));
    ...//rest of the code
    }
```

You need to set the content of your layout the activity first and then intialize views.

Also you need to add your drawing view to your layout.

In `onCreate`

```
     LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.linearlayout);
     // Assuming you have linear layout in your xml add your drawing view to lineasrlayout
     // you can have relative layout also
     DrawingView view = new DrawingView(this);
     ll.addView(View);
```

Edit

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements ColorPickerDialog.OnColorChangedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
      //circlePaint = new Paint();
        //circlePath = new Path();
        //circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        //circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        //circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        //circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        //circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f); 
        //circlePath.reset();
        //circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 },
                                       0.4f, 6, 3.5f);

        mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
    }

    private Paint       mPaint;
    private MaskFilter  mEmboss;
    private MaskFilter  mBlur;

    public void colorChanged(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    public class MyView extends View {

        private static final float MINP = 0.25f;
        private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

        private Bitmap  mBitmap;
        private Canvas  mCanvas;
        private Path    mPath,circlePath;
        private Paint   mBitmapPaint,circlePaint;

        public MyView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            circlePaint = new Paint();
            circlePath = new Path();
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
            circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f); 

            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            circlePath.reset();
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static final int COLOR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int EMBOSS_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int BLUR_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    private static final int ERASE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
    private static final int SRCATOP_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, COLOR_MENU_ID, 0, "Color").setShortcut('3', 'c');
        menu.add(0, EMBOSS_MENU_ID, 0, "Emboss").setShortcut('4', 's');
        menu.add(0, BLUR_MENU_ID, 0, "Blur").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, ERASE_MENU_ID, 0, "Erase").setShortcut('5', 'z');
        menu.add(0, SRCATOP_MENU_ID, 0, "SrcATop").setShortcut('5', 'z');

        /****   Is this the mechanism to extend with filter effects?
        Intent intent = new Intent(null, getIntent().getData());
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        menu.addIntentOptions(
                              Menu.ALTERNATIVE, 0,
                              new ComponentName(this, NotesList.class),
                              null, intent, 0, null);
        *****/
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case COLOR_MENU_ID:
                new ColorPickerDialog(this, this, mPaint.getColor()).show();
                return true;
            case EMBOSS_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case BLUR_MENU_ID:
                if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
                } else {
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
                }
                return true;
            case ERASE_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                        PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                return true;
            case SRCATOP_MENU_ID:
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                                                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
                mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ColorPickerDialog

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog {

    public interface OnColorChangedListener {
        void colorChanged(int color);
    }

    private OnColorChangedListener mListener;
    private int mInitialColor;

    private static class ColorPickerView extends View {
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Paint mCenterPaint;
        private final int[] mColors;
        private OnColorChangedListener mListener;

        ColorPickerView(Context c, OnColorChangedListener l, int color) {
            super(c);
            mListener = l;
            mColors = new int[] {
                0xFFFF0000, 0xFFFF00FF, 0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FFFF, 0xFF00FF00,
                0xFFFFFF00, 0xFFFF0000
            };
            Shader s = new SweepGradient(0, 0, mColors, null);

            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setShader(s);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(32);

            mCenterPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mCenterPaint.setColor(color);
            mCenterPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }

        private boolean mTrackingCenter;
        private boolean mHighlightCenter;

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            float r = CENTER_X - mPaint.getStrokeWidth()*0.5f;

            canvas.translate(CENTER_X, CENTER_X);

            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(-r, -r, r, r), mPaint);
            canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, CENTER_RADIUS, mCenterPaint);

            if (mTrackingCenter) {
                int c = mCenterPaint.getColor();
                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                if (mHighlightCenter) {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
                } else {
                    mCenterPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
                }
                canvas.drawCircle(0, 0,
                                  CENTER_RADIUS + mCenterPaint.getStrokeWidth(),
                                  mCenterPaint);

                mCenterPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                mCenterPaint.setColor(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
        }

        private static final int CENTER_X = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_Y = 100;
        private static final int CENTER_RADIUS = 32;

        private int floatToByte(float x) {
            int n = java.lang.Math.round(x);
            return n;
        }
        private int pinToByte(int n) {
            if (n < 0) {
                n = 0;
            } else if (n > 255) {
                n = 255;
            }
            return n;
        }

        private int ave(int s, int d, float p) {
            return s + java.lang.Math.round(p * (d - s));
        }

        private int interpColor(int colors[], float unit) {
            if (unit <= 0) {
                return colors[0];
            }
            if (unit >= 1) {
                return colors[colors.length - 1];
            }

            float p = unit * (colors.length - 1);
            int i = (int)p;
            p -= i;

            // now p is just the fractional part [0...1) and i is the index
            int c0 = colors[i];
            int c1 = colors[i+1];
            int a = ave(Color.alpha(c0), Color.alpha(c1), p);
            int r = ave(Color.red(c0), Color.red(c1), p);
            int g = ave(Color.green(c0), Color.green(c1), p);
            int b = ave(Color.blue(c0), Color.blue(c1), p);

            return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
        }

        private int rotateColor(int color, float rad) {
            float deg = rad * 180 / 3.1415927f;
            int r = Color.red(color);
            int g = Color.green(color);
            int b = Color.blue(color);

            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            ColorMatrix tmp = new ColorMatrix();

            cm.setRGB2YUV();
            tmp.setRotate(0, deg);
            cm.postConcat(tmp);
            tmp.setYUV2RGB();
            cm.postConcat(tmp);

            final float[] a = cm.getArray();

            int ir = floatToByte(a[0] * r +  a[1] * g +  a[2] * b);
            int ig = floatToByte(a[5] * r +  a[6] * g +  a[7] * b);
            int ib = floatToByte(a[10] * r + a[11] * g + a[12] * b);

            return Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), pinToByte(ir),
                              pinToByte(ig), pinToByte(ib));
        }

        private static final float PI = 3.1415926f;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX() - CENTER_X;
            float y = event.getY() - CENTER_Y;
            boolean inCenter = java.lang.Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) <= CENTER_RADIUS;

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mTrackingCenter = inCenter;
                    if (inCenter) {
                        mHighlightCenter = true;
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (mHighlightCenter != inCenter) {
                            mHighlightCenter = inCenter;
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    } else {
                        float angle = (float)java.lang.Math.atan2(y, x);
                        // need to turn angle [-PI ... PI] into unit [0....1]
                        float unit = angle/(2*PI);
                        if (unit < 0) {
                            unit += 1;
                        }
                        mCenterPaint.setColor(interpColor(mColors, unit));
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (mTrackingCenter) {
                        if (inCenter) {
                            mListener.colorChanged(mCenterPaint.getColor());
                        }
                        mTrackingCenter = false;    // so we draw w/o halo
                        invalidate();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                             OnColorChangedListener listener,
                             int initialColor) {
        super(context);

        mListener = listener;
        mInitialColor = initialColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnColorChangedListener l = new OnColorChangedListener() {
            public void colorChanged(int color) {
                mListener.colorChanged(color);
                dismiss();
            }
        };

        setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), l, mInitialColor));
        setTitle("Pick a Color");
    }
}
```

Comment: the definition of button are already defined in on create .. i have posted but after post code is jumbled ..

Comment: DrawView :
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0a5sSLILnBNb0FwLUprczdGVk0/edit
MyView
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0a5sSLILnBNbExIV0l0SnhlN3c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i have define all the necessary thing ..paint on canvas is going awesome but i cant change the color from button click

Comment: @user1593373 whyh do you have this `MyView.this.coloringView.setColor("#FA8072")`. What is `Myview`?.

Comment: MyView is the class which contain all button ... now i call setcolor() which is a function on drawview to change the color

Comment: @user1593373 is your myview set to the your activity layout?

Comment: @user1593373 just saw `MyView.java`. you have many buttons do you require all of those. i suggest you reconsider your design.

Comment: wait m sending the layout of this .. 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0a5sSLILnBNc2FWZC1raVc2U00/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you have around 100 buttons which is not a a design.  suggest you rethink your design.

Comment: yes i have 100 button but this not the issue .. issue is on button click why it is showing that null exception instead of changing color

Comment: @user1593373 100 buttons is a bigger issue than your nullpointerexcpetion. pls rethink your design/your app flow.

Comment: @user1593373 use a color picker dialog if you want to choose a color. i have updates with a edit. having 100 buttons doesn't make sense.