# Changing path color without changing previous paths

Tags: android, list, colors, path, ondraw

I made straight lines with the canvas.drawPath command. But now I want that the color is selectable. So you click on a button and afterwards, the path is in this color, but the previous paths remain in their colors.. The thin with the button comes later, the colour is random at the moment...

I did it, i changed the code from here! [Change path color without changing previous paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316382/change-path-color-without-changing-previous-paths)

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.drawproject;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DrawArea da = new DrawArea(this);
    setContentView(da);
}
}
```

**Draw Activity**

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.*;
 import android.util.SparseArray;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Random;

public class DrawArea extends View {

private List<Stroke> _allStrokes; //all strokes that need to be drawn
private SparseArray<Stroke> _activeStrokes; //use to retrieve the currently drawn     strokes
private Random _rdmColor = new Random();


int count = 1;
public DrawArea(Context context) {
    super(context);
    _allStrokes = new ArrayList<Stroke>();
    _activeStrokes = new SparseArray<Stroke>();
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (_allStrokes != null) {
        for (Stroke stroke: _allStrokes) {
            if (stroke != null) {
                Path path = stroke.getPath();
                Paint painter = stroke.getPaint();
                if ((path != null) && (painter != null)) {
                    if(count%2 != 0){
                    canvas.drawPath(path, painter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getActionMasked();
    final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            count++;
            if(count%2 != 1)
            {pointDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY(), event.getPointerId(0));
            break;
            }
            if (count%2 != 0){
                for (int pc = 0; pc < pointerCount; pc++) {
                    pointDown((int)event.getX(pc), (int)event.getY(pc), event.getPointerId(pc));
        }
            }
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            break;
        }

    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

private void pointDown(int x, int y, int id) {

    if(count%2 !=1){
    //create a paint with random color
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    paint.setColor(_rdmColor.nextInt());

    //create the Stroke
    Point pt = new Point(x, y);
    Stroke stroke = new Stroke(paint);
    stroke.addPoint(pt);
    _activeStrokes.put(id, stroke);
    _allStrokes.add(stroke);
    }

    if (count%2 != 0){
    //retrieve the stroke and add new point to its path
    Stroke stroke = _activeStrokes.get(id);
    if (stroke != null) {
        Point pt = new Point(x, y);
        stroke.addPoint(pt);
    }
    }
}
}
```

**Lines**

```
package com.example.drawproject;

import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;

public class Stroke {
private Path _path;
private Paint _paint;

public Stroke (Paint paint) {
    _paint = paint;
}

public Path getPath() {
    return _path;
}

public Paint getPaint() {
    return _paint;
}

public void addPoint(Point pt) {
    if (_path == null) {
        _path = new Path();
        _path.moveTo(pt.x, pt.y);
    } else {
        _path.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each path declare separate paint object and change paint object of the path that you want to change.

```
    canvas.drawPath(path1, paint1);
    canvas.drawPath(path2, paint2);
    canvas.drawPath(path3, paint3);
    canvas.drawPath(path4, paint4);
```

The main idea:

public class temp extends View{

```
  private Map<Path,Paint> MyMap = new HashMap<Path,Paint>();


public ViewFeld(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    init();

  }

private void init() {

    for (int i = 0; i < number of pathes ; i++) {
        Path path = new Path();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        MyMap.put(path, paint);

    }
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    for (Path p  : MyMap.keySet()) {
        canvas.drawPath(p, MyMap.get(p));
    }

}
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


        Paint p = MyMap.get(path you want to change the color);
        // change the color of p

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

      break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      // nothing to do
      break;
    default:
      return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Ok yes I thought about something like this, but I have a bit problems with the transcription. Should I make a Paint,Path Arraylist or how can I achiev it?

Comment: I think you should use map, look at this for detail:http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/map.html and something like this Map<Path, Paint> map = new HashMap<Path, Paint>();

Comment: this is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316382/change-path-color-without-changing-previous-paths
there is a answer for multi touch and color changing and it's done without Map, do you think I could change this code somehow, so it works for me?